# how to install pandas 13 on crunchbang linux

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to linux but I've tried every method I can think of to install the latest version of the pandas library for data analysis to work with the python programming language.

I use crunchbang 11 the debian one waldolf.

Ive tried sudo apt-get install pandas 13.0

no matter what I do download from website or through some repo it always installs version 08 on my machine. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have not already setup any other python development environment, it would be much convenient to install [Anaconda](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install.html). It will come with some other tools which will make your life way more easier. It will install latest Pandas and some other libraries like NumPy/SciPy on which Pandas depend. If you wish you can keep it separated from your system's default python setup.

Comment: I would like to just install it via another method, since I want the same setup at work and cannot use anaconda at work.

Comment: Have you tried using [pip(pypi)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi)? Unfortunately I do not have my Linux system with me for couple of days so I cannot try it myself. But pip(pypi) should be able to retrieve the latest python libraries.

Comment: Looks like you can get pandas .13 with python 3.
http://ftp.is.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/pandas/

Comment: does that ftp site mean I have to compile from source, no idea how to do that?! yes I have tried pip and easy install, both only install version 8 of pandas on crunchbang 11 debian waldolf. thank you.

Comment: It's a .deb file so you do not need to compile. Only need to force install some dependency. And my mistake pandas 0.13 with python 2.7 is also available on that page.

Comment: thanks quazi, right now for some reason my ipython notebook installation says that the dataframe pd.read_excel doesn't exist. could it possibly have something to do with I only have pandas 8 installed?

Comment: If I do need to upgrade to 2.7.6 or even 3.3 (though im not sure some other libraries will work) can someone please point me where to get it. The debian repository clearly labels python 3 in the name of the file but not other versions such as 2.7.6 or 2.7?

Comment: Can you post exactly what error does it give? Have you already installed pandas .13?

Comment: no it won't install without numpy 1.7.0 or greater. I downloaded numpy 1.7.2 but it installs, and pandas 13 still says missing dependency? So still unsure why I'm getting the error >>>

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'read_excel'

Not sure if it is 1. version of python I installed, 2. Pandas 8 doesn't have read_excel and I need 13.0? New To Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads)!  If you're new to Linux and Python and Pandas and don't know how to build packages from source, use [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads)!

There are other ways to install but, but you're going to suffer with dependencies and processes that are unfamiliar and will only frustrate you.  Give it a year, learn Linux, Python and Pandas, then try to install from scratch.  You'll be happier and better prepared for all the snags.